# Correct way to cancel TPL data flow block

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow, cancellationtokensource

I am using `TPL` blocks to carry out operation that may be cancelled by user:
I have come up with two options, in first I cancel whole block but don't cancel operation inside the block, like this:

```
_downloadCts = new CancellationTokenSource();

var processBlockV1 = new TransformBlock<int, List<int>>(construct =>
{
    List<int> properties = GetPropertiesMethod(construct );
    var entities = properties
        .AsParallel()
        .Select(DoSometheningWithData)
        .ToList();
    return entities;
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { CancellationToken = _downloadCts.Token });
```

and the second I cancel inside operation, but not the block itself:

```
var processBlockV2 = new TransformBlock<int, List<int>>(construct =>
{
    List<int> properties = GetPropertiesMethod(construct);
    var entities = properties
        .AsParallel().WithCancellation(_downloadCts.Token)
        .Select(DoSometheningWithData)
        .ToList();
    return entities;
});
```

As I understand, first option will cancel whole block, thus shutting down the whole pipeline. My question is will it also cancel inside operation and dispose of all resources if there are any(open StreamReaders, ect.) or is it better to choose second option for then I myself can make sure everything is cancelled and cleaned and then I could use some means(railway programming) to float raised `OperationCanceledException` down the pipe and deal with it where I want?

Comment: you should pass your cancellation token to all  methods

Comment: _"Cancel"_ just means you are _requesting a desire_ for things to end.  Unless something checks for this flag it won't end.  This means `DoSometheningWithData()` should also be examining `_downloadCts` perhaps with `_downloadCts.ThrowIfCancellationRequested ()`.  If you are dealing with disposable resources, place them in a `using()` block to ensure they are tossed away

Comment: The true power of TPL is to build a pipeline from several different building blocks. So it was designed in a way that whenever the `ISourceBlock` ends (for whatever reason) then it can notify all linked `ITargetBlock`s. In order to work like this you have to specify the following during your `Link` call: `new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true }` My suggestion would be to consider to cancel the **producer** part, not the **consumer**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two options are not equivalent.

1. The first option (`CancellationToken = _downloadCts.Token`) will make the `processBlockV1` block to discard any messages that are currently in its buffer (its [`InputCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.transformblock-2.inputcount) property will become `0`), and stop accepting new messages (invoking its [`Post`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.post) method will invariably return `false`). It will not stop processing the messages that are currently in progress though. These will be processed fully, but will not be propagated to any linked blocks. After these messages are processed, the block will complete in a canceled state (its [`Completion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.idataflowblock.completion)[`.Status`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.status) property will become `Canceled`).
2. The second option (canceling the inside operations) will have no effect to the block as a whole. The Dataflow blocks tolerate any [`OperationCanceledException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.operationcanceledexception) thrown from their processing function, and just ignore the faulted item and proceed with the next one. So after the cancellation of the token, all posted messages are still going to be processed, and the block will continue accepting more. It just won't propagate anything to its linked blocks, because all items will throw the `OperationCanceledException` and get ignored. In the specific example the `GetPropertiesMethod` method will be invoked for all `construct` messages, and so will impose a delay to the completion of the block. The final state of the block will be `RanToCompletion`.

It is important to know that the Dataflow blocks are taking seriously the concept of `Completion`. They will wait for everything that they know to stop running before reporting completion. In case you do want them to complete prematurely and leave behind tasks that are still running, you'll have to do tricks like [wrapping your tasks with cancelable wrappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58330380/how-to-force-an-actionblock-to-complete-fast).

Comment: Hi, Theodor, thank you for answer! Based on this information, I think best scenario for my case would be to use `new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { CancellationToken = _downloadCts.Token }` in block definition itself and then pass the same token to inside processing method to stop whatever it is doing. I tested it and the same token is able to cancel block and then it "fires" again in the inside method. My question is - is it guaranteed that it will always fire second time in the inside method?

Comment: Hi @niks! Yes, it will fire for all items that are currently processed. The number of currently processed items depends mainly on the setting [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) that is passed into the block's constructor. By default is one.

Comment: I see. One more interesting thing is that if I use Try library(https://github.com/StephenCleary/Try) and wrap exceptions so they can be passed down the pipe, if  `CancelationToken` is fired both on and inside the `TransformBlock` the `OperationCanceledException` does not float down to final block even though it is thrown in the inside processing method. Not sure if this is a problem, but I assume it is something one should pay attention to when implementing such solution.

Comment: @niks yes, I have noticed this too, and it doesn't seem very logical TBH. In practice though the same cancellation token is usually passed to all blocks of a pipeline, so in most cases this unexpected behavior has not a chance to emerge.

Comment: Hmm..I am now thinking if I pass the same `cancelationToken` to all blocks and I am using aforementioned `Try` library that wraps each exception and floats it down the pipe as a simple value, does setting `new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true }` when linking blocks together has any real functionality?

Comment: @niks in theory it could be possible for the `PropagateCompletion = true` to preempt the cancellation through the token, resulting to some blocks completing erroneously as successful instead of canceled. But in practice it seems that there is no race condition. Apparently there is a delay in the propagation of completion, probably intentional, and probably for exactly this reason.

Comment: Got it. You have clarified this issue for me! Once again - Efcharistó!:)

Comment: Parakalo @niks!  Btw I just made a stress test, and after cancelling 10,000 pipelines, none was completed in inconsistent state. So I guess that the race condition has been addressed. I also tested passing a linked token to the second block (so not exactly the same token but almost), and in that case I observed 5 inconsistent completions (out of 10,000).

Comment: So, as long as I use same `CancelationToken` for all blocks, I should be OK then!

Comment: @niks yeap, exactly. But if you want to be absolutely sure you could call `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` just after the awaiting of the final block's `Completion`.